# test method with multiple catch blocks

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I have such method

```
public QueryResult<?> queryForObject(String queryKey, Class<?> clazz, String... queryParams) {
    LOGGER.debug("Attempt to get query by key {}.", queryKey);
    QueryResult<?> result = null;
    try {
        if (null != queryKey) {
            String query = queries.get(queryKey);
            LOGGER.debug("Retrieve query {} from the my using key {}.", query, queryKey);
            query = String.format(query, (Object[]) queryParams); //line 47
            LOGGER.debug("Formatted query {}.", query);
            result = forceApi.query(query, clazz);
            LOGGER.debug("Retrieved object {} using ForceApi", result);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (ApiTokenException exc) {
        throw exc;
    } catch (ApiException exc) {
        throw exc;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new SpecialRuntimeException(exc); // there NullPointerException line 59
    }
}
```

I want to test whole method - block `try` and all `catch` blocks.

I wrote a test for block try

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testQueryForObjectReturn() {
    Map<String, String> queries = createMock(Map.class);
    QueryResult<?> result = createMock(QueryResult.class);
    mockStatic(String.class);

    expect(queries.get(QUERY_KEY)).andReturn(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    expect(String.format(StringUtils.EMPTY, QUERY_PARAMS)).andReturn(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    expect(forceApi.query(StringUtils.EMPTY, Account.class)).andReturn((QueryResult<Account>) result);
    replayAll();
    queryTemplate.setQueries(queries); // line 61
    queryTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY_KEY, Account.class, QUERY_PARAMS);
    verifyAll();
}
```

It throws NullPointerException.

My class declaration and `setUp` method looks like this.

```
public class SalesforceQueryTemplateTest {

    private static final String QUERY_KEY = "QUERY";
    private static final String QUERY_PARAMS = "1234";

    private ForceApi forceApi;
    private SalesforceQueryTemplate queryTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        forceApi = createStrictMock(ForceApi.class);
        queryTemplate = new SalesforceQueryTemplate();
        queryTemplate.setForceApi(forceApi);
    }
```

What is wrong?
P.S. every time I've got some trouble with testing...

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxadapters.salesforce.repository.query.SalesforceQueryTemplate.queryForObject(SalesforceQueryTemplate.java:47) ~[bin/:na]
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxsalesforce.repository.query.SalesforceQueryTemplateTest.testQueryForObjectReturn(SalesforceQueryTemplateTest.java:61) [bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxcommon.exception.SpecialRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxadapters.salesforce.repository.query.SalesforceQueryTemplate.queryForObject(SalesforceQueryTemplate.java:59)
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxsalesforce.repository.query.SalesforceQueryTemplateTest.testQueryForObjectReturn(SalesforceQueryTemplateTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxadapters.salesforce.repository.query.SalesforceQueryTemplate.queryForObject(SalesforceQueryTemplate.java:47)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: In which line you get the NPE. Add stacktrace.

Comment: @Jens, added. It basically throws runtimeException instead of returning result

Comment: I can not see any stacktrace

Comment: Why are you mocking `Map`? It's a value object. Create a `Map` with the desired values instead.

Comment: And why are you mocking `String.format()`? It is a pure-function, and you want to make sure your code works with the real version of `String.format()`

Answer (score 0):

I thing problem is here:

```
forceApi = createStrictMock(ForceApi.class);
queryTemplate = new SalesforceQueryTemplate();
```

Non-static variable was initialized at the time of object creation. In your code, you have assigned a value before object creation.

Try this instead:

```
queryTemplate = new SalesforceQueryTemplate();
forceApi = createStrictMock(ForceApi.class);
```